# How can I convert 1 element of an int array to a string/char

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, int

When I try to write for example `arr[0] = 'y';` and I try to print it it will print "121" because 121 is 'y' in the ASCII table. How can I convert it so the array element will replace it with an actual 'y'?

```
int example [2] = {16,2};
```

How do I convert for example  `16` to the letter 'y' so if I print the whole array it'd print "y2" and not `1212`?

Print format:

```
int r[2] = {12,43};
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        cout << r[i];
    }
```

Comment: why not use string?

Comment: @bolov String could work too

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Be sure to show all variable declarations as well as how you print output.

Comment: @John3136  One second

Comment: @Nope What is a simple print?

Comment: @Nope Please show the actual line of code that you use to print.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did

Comment: @eerorika I did

Comment: you can cast 121 to a char when printing to get `"y"` (`cout << (char)r[i]`) but then your `2` will not be printed as a `"2"`

Comment: @kmdreko It doesn't work it prints the same thing

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. The phrasing is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are homogeneous. All elements of the array have the same type. When you have an array of `int`, then all elements have the type `int`.

When you insert an `int` into a character stream, the output will be a number, with equivalent format to `num_put::put()`.

So, if you want to see output like `y`, then you must insert either a character, or a character string. If you want to output one object like a character, and another like an integer, then those objects must have a different type.

Characters are integers (with special treament), and convertible to and from `int` (although not all `int` values are representable as `char`). Example using such conversion:

```
int example [2] = {'y',2};
std::cout << char(example[0]) <<  example[1];
```

Comment: Can't you change it? For example
if the array was like this int example [2] = {'y',2};
You can do that char(example[0]='x') or something like that

Comment: The values of the elements can be changed, yes. The types cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to *associate* letters with numbers is to use `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, char> conversions;
//...
map[16] = 'y';
//...
std::cout << map[16] << std::endl;
```

You could also use an array of char:

```
static const char conversion_array[] =
{'F', ..., 'y', ...};
std::cout << conversion_array[16] << std::endl;
```

Comment: I know I can use an array of char but I am not intrsted of doing that. Can you please show me the map example on the code the I posted? How to use it there

Comment: Did you see my example of using `std::map`?  You wanted to associate the number 16 with the character 'y'.  (In ASCII encodings, the first printable character starts at 32).

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
short my_short = 12;
char my_character = static_cast<char>(my_short);

std::cout << my_character << std::endl;
```

Will print a char

std::ostream has an overloaded operator<< for chars, which allows you to print the char instead of printing an integer

Comment: You want me to spoonfeed him? I'm just telling him what's up, he can iterate over the `int[]` and just do the static_cast for each character.